# How to set font-height for all future frames?

Tags: frames, fonts

I've set the font-family and font-size in a few different ways before, one of which was:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:family "Liberation Mono" :height 150)))))
```

However, I learned that if you set it that way, future frames will not be able to use the values and they need something like:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             '(font . "Liberation Mono"))
```

But because I add set it from a variable, I do it like:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             `(font . ,custom-variable-font-family))
```

I'm not able to find a way to set the font-height using this method. I did try to set `height`, but it ended up setting the height of the Emacs frame, just like it's mentioned in one of the documentation pages [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-Parameters.html#Size-Parameters).

I also tried a few other keywords apart for `font` (some from the documentation and some from my own wild guesses), just like you can set the `background-color`, etc. But I haven't been able to do that. I wonder if it's even possible (I know it should be) to set the font-height across frames that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x customize-face default`, then set the `height` attribute to the value you want.

---

There are several other approaches.  Here's one involving `default-frame-alist`:

Use `M-x customize-option default-frame-alist`, providing a full font name for the value of frame-parameter `font`.  For example: this value uses a font height of 16 pixels:

```lisp
"-*-Lucida Console-normal-r-*-*-16-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1"
```

That's an XLFD font name, the traditional method for specifying fonts
under X Window.  See (emacs) [Fonts](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html) for a detailed description.  In this case, the `16` is the `PIXELS` entry. That same Emacs-manual node also describes other ways to specify a font name.

Customize is your friend.  If you don't want to use it then just do what you were doing, but use a full (e.g., XLFD) font name, which specifies the font size.

Comment: I've never used `customized` but only performed customization through scripts, which is something I prefer as it does exactly what I want, is very portable, and I get to learn a thing or two every time I change something. I'll definitely try the XLDF font name though.

Comment: Customize takes of any `:set` etc. automatic code that might need to take place when a given option is set. Just using `setq` does not do that. And it helps you avoid setting an invalid value, and tells you when a value is invalid. Define a separate `custom-file`, load it in your init file, and using Customize will no longer write to your init file (it will use `custom-file`).

Comment: I already have my weird/unusual/super-complicated setup that specifies a `custom-file` [here](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/configs/default/.emacs.d/myTerminal/config-system.el) I did that to prevent Emacs from writing autogenerated code to my `init.el` file, but never used `customize` myself. Your suggestion makes sense though.

Comment: I just tried it today with an XLFD font name and it does work as expected. One of the differences is that now I'm using size in pixels instead of (1/10pts) size.

Comment: Yes, that is a difference. You can also try the other things described in that same Emacs-manual node ([Fonts](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html)).